# Unable to reset SQL id to 1

Tags: mysql, jpa, nativequery

I am unable to reset the id of the objects that I am adding to SQL, through JPA. I tried to write a native query to truncate when I use my deleteAll method, which works, no errors, but the autogenerated id is still not 1.
I tried "ALTER TABLE task AUTO_INCREMENT = 1" after deleting, same result.

My method used for resetting

```
 @Transactional
 @Modifying
 @Query(value = "ALTER TABLE task AUTO_INCREMENT = 1", nativeQuery = true)
    void resetId();
```

My entity id

```
public class Task {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

Comment: Have you checked the result of the delete

Comment: if you mean to check if my table is empty after making a delete request in Postman, then yes

Comment: What is the strategy used by your JPA provider for GenerationType.AUTO? It might not be what you think it is, as this lets the provider pick what it wants/thinks is best for your DB. Check out what statements it issues when inserting to see. You should be able to test the insert yourself in a DB client to execute your own inserts, delete all and the ALTER table statement to verify you have it right, without resorting to JPA or postman for testing.

Comment: There is TRUNCATE TABLE statement in MySQL which resets the AUTO_INCREMENT. However, resetting IDs is generally considered unnecessary and may cause problems.

Comment: Yeah, truncate did sadly not work either, I will try to change the strategy for the GeneratedValue, thanks.

Comment: So, with GenerationType.TABLE I managed to reset the id once, but now I am not able to do it anymore, it still deletes the records, but the id stays the same. It is really weird.